# Find ads for blog

Tags: advertising, cpc-ads

I have a blog and I want to monetize it. I have applied to Google ads but they are saying that my blog has duplicate content.  Is there any site like Google AdSense where I can get ads for my blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article that has [5 Google Adsense Alternatives](http://www.technobuffalo.com/2012/07/01/google-adsense-alternatives/).  It recommends:

- [AdBrite](http://www.adbrite.com/)
- [Bidvertiser](http://www.bidvertiser.com/)
- [Chitika](http://chitika.com/)
- [Clicksor](http://www.clicksor.com/)
- [eClickZ](http://www.eclickz.com/)